# Showing a toast when posting a handler

Tags: android, kotlin

I have tried every context, `this`, `getApplicationContext()`, but it's not working.

```
 class MyServerThread : Runnable {
    internal lateinit var s: Socket
    internal lateinit var ss: ServerSocket
    internal lateinit var isr: InputStreamReader
    internal lateinit var bf: BufferedReader
    internal lateinit var message: String
    internal var h = Handler()


    override fun run() {
        try {
            ss = ServerSocket(3050)
            while (true) {
                s = ss.accept()
                isr = InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream())
                bf = BufferedReader(isr)
                message = bf.readLine()
                h.post {
                    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                }
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

What can I do to fix the issue?

Comment: In Toast.makeText(), i have used all context, this, getApplicationContext(), but still i am getting error in Toast.makeText() section. please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:** Try this code

```
class MyServerThread(val context: Context) : Runnable {
    internal lateinit var s: Socket
    internal lateinit var ss: ServerSocket
    internal lateinit var isr: InputStreamReader
    internal lateinit var bf: BufferedReader
    internal lateinit var message: String
    internal var h = Handler()


    override fun run() {
        try {
            ss = ServerSocket(3050)
            while (true) {
                s = ss.accept()
                isr = InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream())
                bf = BufferedReader(isr)
                message = bf.readLine()
                h.post {
                    Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a Runnable, not a Context object. And Runnables do not have a `getApplicationContext` method

You must add a constructor to this class that accepts a valid Context, which you can pass to the Toast

Comment: please brief it out with an example..!

Comment: It is very important project, i need a help please help me. that how to add a constructor to this class that accepts a valid Context, through which i can pass to the Toast

Comment: Are you having trouble understanding how constructors are written? https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html

Answer (score 0):

Simply add constructor in the Runnable

```
Context context;
public MyServerThread(Context context) {
    this.context=context;
 }
```

Inside the activity (to pass the context)

```
MyServerThread name=new MyServerThread(getBaseContext());
```

Then Finally pass the context in the toast:

```
Toast.makeText(context,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```